# Multiplexing Internet connections

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, usb, multiplexing

I'm looking for some way to multiplex my internet connections so that I can use them simultaneously.

I have a wi-fi/lan connection and a USB dongle that let me connect to the internet, Now the wi-fi/lan connection is a little un-reliable and has a few restrictions so I have to switch to using the USB when the lan is down.

I also need the lan to connect to my local subnet, because there are some subnet only websites I need to access also.

I'm looking for something that will let me use the LAN/Wi-Fi and USB-Dongle simultaneously and preferably let me set what internet connection to use for which set of domain names.

I'm working on a laptop with Fedora 15.
I would also prefer Free (and Open Source if possible) Software.

---

Further reading gives me some indication of a linux Ethernet bonding driver, but this does not seem to be what I am looking for.

This is close to I want http://www.connectify.me/dispatch/ but it is Windows only for now and Paid.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Server 2012 there is NIC teaming which allows the system to see all connections as one physical internet connection . I know it does not directly answer you question but may be a starting point of research. Just my 2p's worth

Comment: I'll take a look.